# Azure VM losing Static IP addresses after restart

Tags: azure, networking, virtual-machine, ip-address

I have around 30 VMs on Azure and all have static IP-Addresses. Now suddenly after a restart, one has changed to Dynamic address and got a new IP address.
This happens for 2 machines so far within a 2 weeks period.
How can that happen and how can I get back previous IP addresses since they are registered in a firewall that provides a service to us?
BR
Amin

Comment: Are you referring to public IP or the Private IP ?

Answer (score 0):

I did reproduce your issue and found that.

**Point 1**: Went to ipconfig and make it as static Ip address and did check after restart and stop as well I am getting the same static Ip address.

[image]
[image]

**Point 2**: Manually assign the same static IP address in VM itself now I can’t connect to my VM.

So, we don't recommend to make any change on the NIC card settings on the VM.

[image]

**Point 3**: Permanent solution for this not to lost the static Ip address is use the PowerShell command to create a Virtual Machine with the static IP address. If you configure the settings on the NIC card, after reboot it may change the IP address, so the best way to set static IP address is as per the recommended way in the article above.

[PowerShell Command to Set Static Private IP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ip-services/virtual-networks-static-private-ip-arm-ps)

[PowerShell Command to Set Static Public IP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ip-services/virtual-network-deploy-static-pip-arm-ps)

Reference : [Azure VM looses static IP after stopping and starting the VM in the portal?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/95fa9147-c70e-4040-ade3-dba184dd44b7/azure-vm-looses-static-ip-after-stopping-and-starting-the-vm-in-the-portal-?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork)